# JavaScript detect Popup window closed by window.close() or by mouse click

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to different if a popup window is closed by `window.close()` or closed by mouse click? I want to different if user manually closed the popup or not.

Answer (score 0):

check-in close event listener if the user clicks a close button then you get data and you know the user clicks manually otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the **onbeforeunload** event to the window AFTER it is opened.

The simplest way to do that would be to have the javascript **onbeforeunload** code within the window source code.

```
var pop_up_window = window.open('some url')
pop_up_window.onbeforeunload = function(){ /* your code */ }
```

Please check following for more details

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event
```